# App Engine / Google Cloud storage Input stream error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am having a problem with writing bytes of a retrieved `ObjectInputStream` object. I need this to be able to access the file in the format.

**This is the code I am currently using:**

```
public ObjectInputStream serve(String fileName) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {

    GcsFilename gcsFileName = getFileName(fileName, defaultbucketName);

    int fileSize = (int) gcsService.getMetadata(gcsFileName).getLength();
    GcsInputChannel readChannel = null;

    readChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(gcsFileName, 0,
            fileSize);

    try (ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(
            Channels.newInputStream(readChannel))) {
        return oin;
    }


}
```

When I run the code it fails at the line `ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(readChannel))` with an error, e.g.:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: FFD8FFE0
```

However there are no problems when I emmit the stream to a `HTTPRESPONSE` object.

Comment: `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` returns an `Object`. Your method returns an `ObjectInputStream`. Hence, this code does not compile! Additionally ... Are you sure that the input stream can be treated as an `ObjectInputStream`? I mean, did you use an `ObjectOutputStream` on the sending site for serializing an object?

Comment: it's a typo, it's not supposed to return the object . I should return oin .  But the code still fails at ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(readChannel))

Answer (score 2):

You are likely attempting to access a file which hasn't been written by a `ObjectOutputStream`, which contains a special header.

Therefore, to access the file you should either rewrite its contents with the Google Cloud Storage writing APIs or with a dummy Java program like this one:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject("your content");
oos.close();
```

Later, upload `test.txt` to your GCS bucket.